# How to authenticate in a Facebook Flash application?

Tags: authentication, facebook

I do not understand how I can authenticate a user in a Facebook Flash application. I have read from the documentation that Facebook platform gives arguments, such as user id and session secret, to the Flash application, but how can I inside the Flash application make sure that these arguments are correct and not fake? Should I make some call to some Facebook platform method and check that no error occurs to be sure?

Another question related to Facebook: Can I only store Facebook users' user id's in my own database and not for example users' names? I guess I am not allowed to show users' real names when they are visiting my website directly and not through Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Use this API for flash/flex communication to Facebook services:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/